# JavaScript Loops and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object

I have the following loop below. Data is passed as JSON format. I want to use this for visualisation of a graph. However, I am unable to understand the logic. Can someone elaborate this logic for me please?

```
for (var x = 0; x < id_inter['inters'].length; x++) {
  var src,
    tgt;
  if (id_inter['inters'][x]['ID'] == data.initial[0].ID) {
    src = id_inter['inters'][x]['ID'];
    tgt = id_inter['inters'][x]['ID2'];
  } else {
    src = id_inter['inters'][x]['ID2'];
    tgt = id_inter['inters'][x]['ID'];
  }
  var_edges.push({
    data: {
      src: src,
      src: tgt,
      expt_type: id_inter['inters'][x]['expt'],
      name: id_inter['inters'][x]['name'],
      date: id_inter['inters'][x]['date']
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If you can't understand to logic, how do we suppose to understand it without the complete context in which this code is used?

Comment: I do not think this is a proper question.

Comment: b langetorma, to bzn vote li down lerla moV falourmama? 

The context is between objects and accessing properties.

Answer (score 0):

Is you who write this code ?
Look like  for each `inters` of `id_inter` your are recuperating some informations and adding them to a JSONArray which is named var_edges ...

The struct of `id_inter` looks like something like :

```
id_int : {
          inter:[{
                    id:someid,
                    id2:someid2,
                    expt:something,
                    name:name,
                    date:23/05.2015
                   },
                   {same struct as before with other data},
                   ...
                  ]
          }
```

So in your var_edges you will have a lot of JSON that has the struct (at the end of the loop) :

```
{
   data:{
       src: src,        
       src: tgt,//better to use tgt as key instead of tgt
       expt_type: id_inter['inters'][x]['expt'],
       name: id_inter['inters'][x]['name'],
       date: id_inter['inters'][x]['date']
       }
 }
```

You have to parse this var_edges in order to get every informations returned by the loop (src,type,name,date...)

Notice that you have two key `src` in your data JSON so the value is probably going to be overriden by the `tgt` value and the `src` value will be lost ...

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on `for (var x = 0; x < id_inter['inters'].length; x++) {
  var src,
    tgt;
  if (id_inter['inters'][x]['ID'] == data.initial[0].ID) {
    src = id_inter['inters'][x]['ID'];
    tgt = id_inter['inters'][x]['ID2'];` ?

Comment: this check the value of the current id on the loop at index X and compare it with a probable constant value not depending on the loop and this value is present on data.initial[0] object ... then depending on the value you choose to put ID on src and ID2 on tgt or vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what you mean by 'interpret', but here's what's happening.

There is an object `id_inter.inters` which holds an array of objects. Each of those objects has at least an `ID` and an `ID2` property.

I'm guessing that `data.initial[0].ID`, indicates the start of something, so when that ID matches the one in `id_inter.inters[x].ID` it reverses the `src` and the `tgt` which are normally `id_inter.inters[x].ID` and `id_inter.inters[x].ID2` respectively.

the `var_edges` array then receives the `src` and `tgt` along with some other properties from `id_inter.inters[x]`

I assume that this array is then used for vizualization.

Comment: What do you mean by reverses the src and the tgt ?

Comment: I simply mean that's what the code does. Under one scenario the src is id and the tgt is id2. under another scenario the src is id2 and the tgt is id.-- and btw as @Phoenix pointed out, the value added to the edges array is probably wrong anyway as it has 2 src properties. It probably should have a src and a tgt property.